# Getting a KeyError when attaching attachments to an email

Tags: python, email, smtp, email-attachments

So I'm trying to create an automated email script that reads surnames, recipient emails, and files to be attached from an excel file.

For some reason, when I send the email with the attachments it returns a KeyError, which I think traces back to the placeholder for the filename of the attachment that I'm using `.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename = {file}')` with. Because whenever I change the placeholder, the KeyError specifies what I wrote in it.

Anyways, here's the source code

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
import ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

context = ssl.create_default_context()

sender = 'john@email.com'
sender_pass = '123456789'
email_subject = 'subject'
attachments_list = 'testingemail.xlsx'

body = 'Dear Mx. {surname} body'
    
def attach_attachment(attachment_list, payload):

    # opening excel file into dataframe
    attachments = pd.read_excel(attachment_list, sheet_name = 'attachments')

    for file in attachments['attachments']:
        with open(file, 'rb') as attachment:
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload((attachment).read())

        encoders.encode_base64(part) # encoding attachment
        part.add_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename = {file}',
        )          

        # attaching attachment
        payload.attach(part)      

def composing_email(e_sender, e_password, e_subject, e_recipient, attachment_list):
    # setup the MIME
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = e_sender
    message['To'] = e_recipient
    message['Subject'] = e_subject

    # attaching body and the attachments for the mail
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    attach_attachment(attachment_list, message)
    
    # create SMTP session for sending the mail
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) # gmail port
    session.starttls(context = context) # securing connection
    session.login(e_sender, e_password) # logging into account

    text = message.as_string()

    # actually sending shit
    session.sendmail(e_sender, 
                    e_recipient, 
                    text.format(surname = surname, 
                                receiver_email = recipient, 
                                sender = e_sender,
                                )
                    )

    session.quit()
    print('Mail successfully sent to {surname} with emal {recipient}')
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    surname_email = pd.read_excel('testingemail.xlsx', sheet_name = 'surname_email')
    for surname, recipient in surname_email.itertuples(index=False):
        composing_email(sender, sender_pass, email_subject, recipient, attachments_list)
```

and here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zddj9\Desktop\auto_email\script.py", line 77, in <module>
    composing_email(sender, sender_pass, email_subject, recipient, attachments_list)
  File "c:\Users\zddj9\Desktop\auto_email\script.py", line 64, in composing_email
    text.format(surname = surname,
KeyError: 'file'
```

Comment: pls try this `part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)` and if this does not work pls add the data so this can be recreated and debugged.

Comment: I'll try this first thing in the morning, but the data is just a simple 2 column excel sheet with it sheet name as surname_recipient with 'surname' and 'recipient' for the headers, the rows below are just 'surname1' and 'email1@email.com'. And in another sheet called attachments is just a one column excel sheet with attachment as the header and filenames like 'text.pdf'. I'll edit the question tomorrow with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I needed to use f-string formatting

instead of this

```
part.add_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename = {file}',
        )
```

add an `f` before the argument with the placeholder

```
part.add_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            f'attachment; filename = {file}',
        )
```

The confirmation also wouldn't work without f-string formatting

```
print('Mail successfully sent to {surname} with email {recipient}')
```

It should be this

```
print(f'Mail successfully sent to {surname} with email {recipient}')
```